# How can I create the 'recipe' or R/ or Rx symbol?

Tags: symbols

In medicine, the sign 'R/' or 'Rx' is often used to denote prescription or treatment.

I use it a lot when taking notes in class and I'd like to use it in my LaTeX documents, too. The problem is that it's hard to find out how to write this in LaTeX, because searches like 'latex medicine' or 'latex prescription' will be overflooded by pages about latex allergies.

How can I write this sign in LaTeX?

[image: R/ sign]

Comment: If you put an answer in the same moment as the question, what is the reason of the question?

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke: [Can I answer my own question?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @cgnieder I had the exact same thought. But, have you tried to input this specific symbol to Detexify? For me it did not work out after several trials... Well, there is still the fabulous symbol list. I guess the question is somehow in a grey zone.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the package `textcomp` to get this done:

```
\usepackage{textcomp} %% put this in your preamble
\textrecipe           %% put this where you want to have the R/ sign.
```